# Identify duplicate values in column groupings and then add a text label to the last group

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The first group contains companies identified as weekly. This includes only Company A, B, and C.

The second group contains companies identified as monthly. This includes only Company D, E, F.

The third group is a long list of companies that need to be defined by the parameters of column a in groups 1 and 2. This list will include Company A to Company J.

So, if a company from Group 1 appears in Group 3, I'd like the 'weekly' status to appear in column A for Group 3. For ex: Cell B2 contains Company A, and since it then appears in Group 3, Cell B14, I'd like the text from cell A2 to duplicate down to cell A14.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkauG.jpg

Answer (score 0):

As formula version, maybe in A14 and copied down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$10,MATCH(B14,B$1:B$10,0)),"")
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks a ton! I think I was over-complicating it.